# How i directly go splash screen to sign in or register activity in android?

Tags: android, android-intent

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean to ask that you want to show splash screen before going to Sign-in or Register page ?

Comment: want to go sign in or register screen from splash or you wana skip splash.

Comment: I am new in app development please help?

Comment: Sure, but unless you clear the above two doubts no can proceed to help

Comment: I want to ask that when i start my app it will shows splash screen and after that it automatically open sign in or register page...

Comment: so you want to skip splash screen?

Comment: i think you're asking about `OnBoarding`

Comment: what do you want ? be clear. `1. skip Splash Screen`  or  `2. Open register activity after Splash screen` or  `3. don't want to open register activity after splash screen(you want to open other activity)`

Comment: i want Open register activity after Splash screen.

Comment: After reading all the conversation what I understood is you want to open LoginActivity or RegisterActivity depending upon user login status, right ?

Comment: **Thanks all of you for solving this issue Great experience**

Comment: Thread timerThread = new Thread(){
            public void run(){
                try{
                    sleep(3000);
                }catch(InterruptedException e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }finally{
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SplashScreen.this,LoginActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        };
        timerThread.start();
    }          i just added this.LoginActivity **Thanks all of you**

Comment: what is has to do with android studio or some ide .. it is programming question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);

    int secondsDelayed =1;
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,LoginActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }, secondsDelayed * 1000);
}
```

}

Comment: Try this for going to Login Activtiy

Comment: that's not what `OP` asked for

Comment: when he is not clear and you don't understand his question completely, then why you post answer ?

Comment: his question makes clear he wants to move from splash screen to other. But his comments is confusing. you see it

Comment: @BishnuDudhraj wait until user provide full information dont make guesses.

Comment: user @SohailZahid is absolutely right. You have to wait. Now your answer is very helpful for `OP `.

Answer (score 1):

put this on MainActivity.java

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

     Intent  intent= new Intent(getApplicationContext(),SignIn.class);
     startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two tags you can use against any activity which you want open when user the app to open.

**LAUNCHER**  as `<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />`

**MAIN** as `<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />`

```
        <activity android:name="com.example.activity.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

To jump from one activty to other use the below code.

```
Intent i = new (CurrentActivityName.this , NextActivityName.class);
startActivity(i);
```

Dont forget to add `Next` in manifest.

```
<activity android:name="com.example.activity.NextActivityName">
```

Answer (score 0):

then you should use following code inside your Splash Activity onCreate method:

```
new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {           
    @Override 
    public void run() { 
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, RegisterActivity.class));
    } 
}, 5000);  //where 5000 is time in miliseconds for delay.
```